# images array and display

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview, nsarray

this is my problem:
how can I create an array containing the names of pictures from a certain folder?

My folder---->   ../folder1/
(the folder name will be into a nsstring variable)
In this folder there's an undefined number of images, and i want to put their names into an array.

This array will be used to "navigate" through the images with two buttons.

The final result must be something similar to this

[image]

how can I do this?

Comment: So how did you manage the directory content listing ? Did you run into trouble ?

Comment: so, i've noticed that if all of my images are inside xcode project I dont need to write the filepath at all ... I can access the images just by the filename (no extension needed too)
 
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myPicture"];

Answer (score 0):

Checkout NSFileManager documentation.

```
contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:
```

method will be good in your case - it returns an array of elements in specified directory.

After that you can use lastPathComponent method (NSURL), cutoff extension and you will have clear image name.